# How to pass and return value in SharePoint 2013 REST

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I am able to get all items of SharePoint list using REST API:

```
lists/getbytitle('listname')/items
```

I want to send some div id (string) in request so that can be obtained in response.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get all the list items and display in HTML? Is this a Sharepoint Hosted App?

Comment: Is the problem actually that you define a success function outside of the closure where you do the query? Such as this could fix that: `var id='derp';$.ajax({success:function(){$(id)})`

Comment: @Stephen Yes, This is SharePoint hosted app. I want to get all items of list and bind it in html

Comment: @eirikb I am able to do this. But, if there are multiple requests then that is getting overridden so to avoid that I want to pass div id in request itself and get in response.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly then you need to get your list items via REST (or JSOM) and bind them to a repeater...

```
 <!-- List Record's -->
<div id="tblghNoRecords" style="display: none;">
    <div class="alert alert-info">
    <p>You currently have no Records. Use the "Create New" button to create a new record.</p>
    </div>
 </div>                   
 <table class="table table-striped" id="tblghRecords" style="display: none;">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Col 1 name</th>
                                    <th>Col 2 name</th>
                                    <th>Col 3 name</th>
                                    <th>Col 4 name</th>
                                    <th>Col 5 name</th>
                                    <th>Col 6 name</th>
                                    <th>Manage</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="ghrecordsListRow">
                            </tbody>
  </table>
```

Then just write your JS to bind to the ghrecordsListRow.